# configuring DD4T web site on SDL WEB 8 Error : Tridion.ContentDelivery.Common.Interop

Tags: dd4t, web8

i am trying to configure DD4T 2.0.7  website on Sdl Web 8 getting below error
screen short attached[image]

```
    Could not load file or assembly 'Tridion.ContentDelivery.Common.Interop,
Version=8.1.0.1219, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=ddfc895746e5ee6b' 
or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Comment: What have you tried? This is just a standard .NET error letting you know that it could not find the Web 8 version of Tridion.ContentDelivery.Common.Interop. So apparently you don't have Web 8 installed on that website.

Comment: what provider did you use? although from the error message I indeed would think you used the Web 8 provider but like @PeterKjaer mentions, you are missing the correct Web 8 DLLs

Answer (score 4):

It's trying to load the Web 8 version of Tridion.ContentDelivery.Common.Interop and failing. So it looks like you don't have SDL Web 8 installed on that website.